# Testing for method calls using sinon on module.exports methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

I'm trying to test if a specific method is called given certain conditions using mocha, chai and sinon. Here is the code:

```
function foo(in, opt) {
    if(opt) { bar(); }
    else { foobar(); }
}

function bar() {...}
function foobar() {...}

module.exports = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar,
    foobar:foobar
};
```

Here is the code in my test file:

```
var x = require('./foo'),
    sinon = require('sinon'),
    chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    should = chai.should(),
    assert = require('assert');

describe('test 1', function () {

  it('should call bar', function () {
      var spy = sinon. spy(x.bar);
      x.foo('bla', true);

      spy.called.should.be.true;
  });
});
```

When I do a console.log on the spy it says it wasn't called even thou with manual logging in the bar method I'm able to see it gets called. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong or how to go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've created a `spy`, but the test code doesn't use it. Replace the original `x.bar` with your spy (don't forget to do cleanup!)

```
describe('test 1', function () {

  before(() => {

    let spy = sinon.spy(x.bar);
    x.originalBar = x.bar; // save the original so that we can restore it later.
    x.bar = spy; // this is where the magic happens!
  });

  it('should call bar', function () {
      x.foo('bla', true);

      x.bar.called.should.be.true; // x.bar is the spy!
  });

  after(() => {
    x.bar = x.originalBar; // clean up!
  });

});
```

Comment: Another modification was needed, one must define all the methods in the module.exports and reference them from there by prefixing them with module.exports. Once that is done the tests pass using the method you shown. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @ToniKostelac, one year later, I'm facing the same issue. Unfortunately, I don't get your modification to make Madara's solution work. The methods are already defined in the module.exports of the file to test, do they have to be defined somewhere else too? and where are the references needed? Could you write a sample of code to show me?

Comment: @Noneu sorry for the late response, I wasn't online here for quite a while, but hopefully you've managed to figure this one out. Basically this had to do with any "private" methods that I used inside my modules. Since they weren't defined in the exports I couldn't use a spy on them.